# Selection Condition Array In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

i have PHP code with loop:

```
$explodeResult=explode(", ",$serviceName);
        foreach($explodeResult as $value)
        {
              $sql = "SELECT id,parent,code,name,xs1 as DOWNLOAD, xs2 as UPLOAD
                       FROM sc_params
                      WHERE rfen = 'SERVICE_REQUESTED'
                      AND code = :param1 
                        OR code IN
                        ( 
                            SELECT code 
                             FROM sc_params 
                             WHERE rfen = 'SERVICE_REQUESTED'
                             AND id = (
                            SELECT parent 
                                 FROM sc_params 
                                 WHERE rfen = 'SERVICE_REQUESTED' 
                                 AND code = :param1 )
                        )
                    ";          
            $stmt = oci_parse($this->_conn,$sql);
            oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":param1", $value);
            $rs = oci_execute($stmt);
            if (!$rs) {
                $error = oci_error();
                $this->_err = $error;
                return false;
            }

$product    = Array();
$idx        = $idx2 = 0;
    while ($data = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)) {
    if($data['PARENT'] == 0) {
        $idx++;
        $product[$idx]['id']        = $data['ID'];
        $product[$idx]['name']      = $data['NAME'];
    }
    else {
        $product[$idx][0]['attributeName']   = 'DOWNLOAD';
        $product[$idx][0]['attributeValue'] = $data['DOWNLOAD'];
        $product[$idx][1]['attributeName']   = 'UPLOAD';
        $product[$idx][1]['attributeValue'] = $data['UPLOAD'];
    } 
   }
    print_r ($test_array);
```

Data from query:

```
ID NAME      PARENT DOWNLOAD UPLOAD
1  INTERNET   0      null     null 
10 SPEED      1      2048     512
2  VOICE      0      null     null
12 PSTN       2      null     null
```

the array result is:

Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => INTERNET
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeName] => DOWNLOAD
                        [attributeValue] => 2048
                    )

```
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attributeName] => UPLOAD
                    [attributeValue] => 512
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => VOICE
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attributeName] => DOWNLOAD
                    [attributeValue] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attributeName] => UPLOAD
                    [attributeValue] => 
                )
        )
)
```

But i just want show the `attributeName` and `attributeValue` for `internet` only.. i tried to add `if($data['NAME'][0]='INTERNET')` below `while`, but it doesn't work, `VOICE` still has `attributeName` and `attributeValue`. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a `vardump` of `$data`?

Comment: if you want INTERNET only, why don't  set WHERE condition when query database? so you want this loop to return just one node? not array of INTERNET nodes? just one?

Comment: Two things i can think of looking at `if($data['NAME'][0]=='INTERNET')` 1) Shouldn't your conditional be using '==' vs '=' and 2) you be comparing to `$data['NAME']` instead of `$data['NAME'][0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with your data you have many possibilities how to organize that:

1st just check `null`:

```
elseif (!($data['DOWNLOAD']==null && $data['UPLOAD']==null)) {
        $product[$idx][0]['attributeName']   = 'DOWNLOAD';
        $product[$idx][0]['attributeValue'] = $data['DOWNLOAD'];
        $product[$idx][1]['attributeName']   = 'UPLOAD';
        $product[$idx][1]['attributeValue'] = $data['UPLOAD'];
    }
```

2nd Check current parent name so:

```
if($data['PARENT'] == 0) {

    $idx++;
    $product[$idx]['id']        = $data['ID'];
    $product[$idx]['name']      = $data['NAME'];
    $curParent = $data['NAME'];
} elseif ($curParent == 'INTERNET') {

    $product[$idx][0]['attributeName']   = 'DOWNLOAD';
    $product[$idx][0]['attributeValue'] = $data['DOWNLOAD'];
    $product[$idx][1]['attributeName']   = 'UPLOAD';
    $product[$idx][1]['attributeValue'] = $data['UPLOAD'];
}
```

and 3rd - you can fix your query to get DOWNLOAD and UPLOAD right to the INTERNET row. If you really need that I can help you.